# WSO2 CEP get UDP feed

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep

I have successfully installed wso2 cep engine on Solaris 10 box. As events I'm receiving UDP feed (pipe separated data lines). How can I configure CEP engine to receive the UDP feed and process it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't yet have a UDP data receiver but we welcome you to write one :). You can push the events directly to the CEP engine (look at how the current data receivers do it) or use the data publisher API if you want to send it to a remote CEP engine (via thrift .. which would be kind of silly!). If you choose to write one please join architecture@wso2.org and ask for help / suggestions. See http://wso2.org/mail.

Comment: What is meant by UDP transport in the CEP document?